# Edit like Andrew Bayda or Roman Ivanov ( Vogue Style )

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, wedding, natural-lighting

I'm a wedding photographer and want to change my style.
Does someone know how these people do this vogue style with contrast and colors?
Maybe they are using Capture One?

- http://andrewbayda.com/
- https://roman-ivanov.com/

I already bought the presets but can't do the same. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I note you have tagged your question [natural-lighting](/questions/tagged/natural-lighting); I am assuming you think this means the photos you have linked to were taken with natural light.

**Nothing could be further from the case**: every single one of the photos<sup>1</sup> was taken with a very carefully constructed artificial lighting setup. You will not be able to take photos shot in natural light and edit them to have the same style as these photos, no matter what software and presets you have.

<sup>1. With the obvious exception of the wide-angle outdoor shots, but they are much less stylised anyway.</sup>